# Dialog "Don't show this again" boolean: Where to store value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, boolean

I have a JavaScript pop-up dialog that appears whenever a user calls a specific event, which can be annoying.

I am using Ruby on Rails on server-side with a database connection.

So I am thinking about an input checkbox so that the dialog won't show up again, but the user should be able to change the value again.

Where would I store the boolean value for that? In the database, session, or even cookie?

Comment: did you want right, left or center justified?

Comment: You need to provide more context to your question - such as whether the user 'logs on' to your system, just visits etc. and whether it should persist for just this visit, be configurable or last indefinitely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
                      The answer is, "it depends".

           If you want the setting to persist across visits to
          the site, even from different computers, store it in
                  the user's profile in your database.

            If you don't have a user database, store it in a
                           persistent cookie.

         If you don't want it to persist (too long), store it in
                           the (PHP?) session.

          If you won't want it to persist at all, store it in a
          per-session cookie (i.e. one without an expiry date)
```